# Add white noise on image batch data when training

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, pytorch, noise

I am trying out a de-noise model, the goal is to print out `clean`/ `add_noise`/ `model_output` of each batch.

I am using PyTorch `DataLoader`. Each image has `shape = (256, 128)`, and the set 
`batch_size = 10`, therefore each batch has size `(10, 256, 128)`. I would like to print out the first data of each batch, i.e. `batch_data[0]`

Each image has `shape = (256, 128)`

I've written a function to add noise as below:

```
def add_noise(data, bs, target_snr, noise_type):

    if noise_type == 'white':
        noise = acoustics.generator.white(bs*256*128).reshape(bs, 256, 128)

    if noise_type == 'pink':
        noise = acoustics.generator.pink(bs*256*128).reshape(bs, 256, 128)


    print ('data shape = ', data.shape)

    average = np.mean(data)
    std = np.std(noise)
    current_snr = average/std

    noise = noise * (current_snr/ target_snr)
    data = data + noise

    return data
```

However, it keeps return error message as below:

```
TypeError: mean() missing 3 required positional argument: "dim", "keepdim", "dtype"
```

How should I deal with this?

Comment: My guess is that `data` is a PyTorch `tensor`, but you're using NumPy's `np.mean()` on it. Try replacing `np.mean(data)` with `data.mean()` and same with `np.std()`

Answer (score 0):

What is the shape of your `data`? What is it's `type(data)`?
Are you passing a `DataLoader` Tensor in the Numpy function?

Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) for Numpy's `mean()` function, which also contains some examples.

The function takes an *array-like* object as its input (could be a 2d Matrix for example) so the mean is not immediately clearly defined. Do you need to calculate the mean along the rows, the columns, or of all the data in the matrix? What will be the datatype used in the calculation?

In the first case, you need to provide the dimension you want to flatten your array. In the second case, it should work out of the box with Numpy as *"The default is to compute the mean of the flattened array"*, but since you're working with PyTorch's `DataLoader`, it could need these to be defined.

Since your `average` seems to be a number, something like this should work

```py
average = np.mean(data, axis=(0,1) keepdims=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the first comment under the original post. The data is PyTorch tensor, while I used Numpy's method. I tried using `torch.mean()` & `torch.std()` and it works.